# Copy structure of dirs with files from file.txt

Tags: command-line, bash

I take output from this command to file.txt and have list of dirs.

```
find /path/ -type d > dirs.txt
```

Then I use next command to make this dirs in other location:

```
xargs mkdir -p < dirs.txt
```

Everythin work propably, but now I want to copy dirs with files from txt file to new location. What I should use to take thems?

For example

I got  2 trees of files in /path/dir

```
dir1
├── 1
│   └── file1
├── 2
│   └── file1
├── 3
│   └── file1
├── 4
│   └── file1
├── 5
    └── file1
```

```
dir2
├── 1
├── 2
├── 5
```

And I want take this structure of dir2 to file.txt and then copy dirs with files from dir1 to other location

Comment: Use `rsync` instead. I only today explained it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349296/copy-files-based-on-date-with-structure-of-directories/).

Comment: I don't understand how use this `rsync` to take only specified files from dir1 using dir2

Comment: There is the `--files-from=FILE` command line option, and there is the opposite `--exclude=...` option.

Comment: Thanks! I got this: `rsync -a /source/directory --files-from=/full/path/to/listfile /destination/directory`